# Docker getsockopt: connection refuse

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running a docker server on my Ubuntu machine and I am getting an error when one of the application running into the server tries to open a socket, I get the following error, any clue why this is happening?

I have run the same code in virtual box and I don't see it... Maybe a memory lack issue?

thanks in adnvance,

regards!

```
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:03 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:05 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:07 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:09 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:11 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:13 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:15 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:17 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:19 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:21 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:23 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:25 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:27 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:29 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:31 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:33 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:35 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:37 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:39 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | 2016/04/15 13:55:41 Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:5672: getsockopt: connection refused
croft_1      | panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
croft_1      | [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x401570]


CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O               BLOCK I/O             PIDS
3b4a7e9023ad        0.00%               7.741 MB / 1.039 GB   0.74%               9.314 kB / 5.679 kB   5.046 MB / 0 B        0
6614c0b5c616        0.02%               4.379 MB / 1.039 GB   0.42%               10.02 kB / 648 B      5.009 MB / 0 B        0
658988a96412        3.09%               77.4 MB / 1.039 GB    7.45%               9.83 kB / 648 B       46.69 MB / 17.5 MB    0
9e1c772d7635        0.83%               115.7 MB / 1.039 GB   11.13%              15.12 kB / 5.484 kB   37.06 MB / 147.5 kB   0
0cc07e241f7a        0.22%               102.6 MB / 1.039 GB   9.87%               12.16 kB / 2.652 kB   37.25 MB / 471 kB     0

    ^Clorabackbone@lorabackbone-desktop:~/server-devenv$ docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                        NAMES
    3b4a7e9023ad        serverdevenv_croft      "./croft"                3 hours ago         Up 2 minutes        1700/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1700->1700/udp                                                             serverdevenv_croft_1
    6614c0b5c616        ansi/mosquitto          "/usr/local/sbin/mosq"   3 hours ago         Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:1883->1883/tcp                                                                       serverdevenv_mosquitto_1
    658988a96412        serverdevenv_mongodb    "/entrypoint.sh mongo"   3 hours ago         Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                                                                     serverdevenv_mongodb_1
    9e1c772d7635        rabbitmq:3-management   "/docker-entrypoint.s"   3 hours ago         Up 3 minutes        4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672->5672/tcp, 15671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp   serverdevenv_rabbitmq_1
    0cc07e241f7a        cpswan/node-red         "/usr/local/bin/node-"   3 hours ago         Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:1880->1880/tcp
```

Comment: Can you reach `172.17.0.5:5672` from your container by other means? What does `telnet 172.17.0.5 5672` show?